# Access to the FCM payload in power-saving mode

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

In Flutter, if I kill the application in power saving mode, can I access the payload data for the FCM's push notification?

This has been tested in the background handler, but I haven't been able to achieve what I expected.